# Failing example in openam: exception.name = java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: openam

So I'm following the documentation listed [here](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/10.0.0/dev-guide/index.html#chap-rest):

to create a user:

```
curl "http://localhost:2020/openam/identity/create?
 admin=AQIC5wM2LY4SfczmNJCUo6W4qZZmJe8r46C0tWGQ7ZexXUU.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLAAoxNzk1NTIyMDEwAAJTMQACMDE.*
 &identity_name=testuser
 &identity_attribute_names=cn
 &identity_attribute_values_cn=Test%20User
 &identity_attribute_names=sn
 &identity_attribute_values_sn=User
 &identity_attribute_names=userpassword
 &identity_attribute_values_userpassword=secret12
 &identity_realm=%2F
 &identity_type=user"
```

I'm getting a really strange response:

```
exception.name=java.lang.NullPointerException
```

what could be happening and how might I debug such an error?

Comment: When using OpenAM 11.0.0 you may have recognized that the old IdM REST-API is deprecated, please see http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/dev-guide/index.html#rest-api-create-legacy

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your call and it works fine for me on OpenAM 11.0.0 so I guess you have some issue with your data store configuration. You may check the deployment container log for exception. Furthermore set debug level to 'message' in OpenAM and have a look in IdRepo debug log. Make sure you understand OpenAM data store / IdRepo and notice that OpenAM is not considered to be an IdM /provisioning tool as IdM only works under limited use-cases. OpenAM is not a web-based frontend to an LDAP Directory Server, IdRepo can be virtually any backend system like an SAP HR system.